# In processing, is there matrix stack for common attributes?

Tags: processing

Is there a `pushMatrix()/popMatrix()` analog to this processing code that tries to assign custom attributes to text?

```java
pushMatrix();
textAlign(CENTER);
fill(0, 255, 0);
text("Hello world.", 0, 0);
popMatrix();
```

This code does not work; the `popMatrix()` does not undo the attribute assignments. Any text typed after `popMatrix()` is still center-aligned and green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is, and it applies to all styles(fill(),stroke(),etc.) , not just text attributes: have a look at [pushStyle()](http://processing.org/reference/pushStyle_.html)

From docs:

> The pushStyle() function saves the current style settings and
>   popStyle() restores the prior settings. Note that these functions are
>   always used together. They allow you to change the style settings and
>   later return to what you had. When a new style is started with
>   pushStyle(), it builds on the current style information. The
>   pushStyle() and popStyle() functions can be embedded to provide more
>   control (see the second example above for a demonstration.)
>
> The style information controlled by the following functions are
>   included in the style: fill(), stroke(), tint(), strokeWeight(),
>   strokeCap(), strokeJoin(), imageMode(), rectMode(), ellipseMode(),
>   shapeMode(), colorMode(), textAlign(), textFont(), textMode(),
>   textSize(), textLeading(), emissive(), specular(), shininess(),
>   ambient()