# Processing: Trying to make a paint tool with 2 sidebars. When clicking the brush size one it fills in both sidebars with color

Tags: processing

I have never used processing before and started learning it a bit to help a friend in their course as they have never done any coding before. One of the assignments was to make a simple paint tool that lets you change the color and brush size that you are using. To do this we made a sidebar at the bottom that had all of the color and brush size options which worked fine. I decided I wanted to try moving the brush sizes to a separate sidebar on the side so that there would be more room for more color options and more brush sizes.

The issue I have run into is now whenever I click one of the brush sizes both sidebars get completely filled in with whatever color I have selected. This completely covers all of the buttons in both sidebars so the user can't see the icons to change colors or brush sizes anymore. I cannot figure out what it is that is causing this issue and everything I have tried to change so far hasn't changed it. I'll attach the code and screen shots of program running to better illustrate what I am trying to describe as I am aware I may not have been super clear. Any ideas or help is super appreciated!
[Program on start up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHFoE.png)

[Program after clicking a brush size icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLSeA.png)

```
float g = 0;
float b = 0;

int penSize = 1; 

void setup(){
size(800,650);
background(255);
}

void draw(){
  stroke(r,g,b);
  strokeWeight(penSize);
  if(mousePressed&&mouseY<height-50&&mouseX<width-50){
    line(pmouseX, pmouseY, mouseX, mouseY);
  }
  
  line(0,height-50,width-50,height-50);
  fill(255,0,0);
  rect(0,height-50,50,50);
  fill(0,255,0);
  rect(50,height-50,50,50);
  fill(0,0,255);
  rect(100,height-50,50,50);
  fill(255);
  rect(150,height-50,50,50);
  fill(0);
  rect(200,height-50,50,50);
  fill(100, 0, 255);
  rect(250,height-50,50,50);
  fill(200, 200, 0);
  rect(300,height-50,50,50);

  if(mousePressed&&mouseX<50&&mouseY>height-50){
    r = 255; g = 0; b = 0;
    
  }
  if(mousePressed&&mouseX<100&&mouseX>50&&mouseY>height-50){
    r = 0; g = 255; b = 0;
    
  }
  if(mousePressed&&mouseX<150&&mouseX>100&&mouseY>height-50){
    r = 0; g = 0; b = 255;
    
  }
  if(mousePressed&&mouseX<200&&mouseX>150&&mouseY>height-50){
    r = 255; g = 255; b = 255;
    
  }
  if(mousePressed&&mouseX<250&&mouseX>200&&mouseY>height-50){
    r = 0; g = 0; b = 0;
    
  }
  if(mousePressed&&mouseX<300&&mouseX>250&&mouseY>height-50){
    r = 100; g = 0; b = 255;
    
  }
  if(mousePressed&&mouseX<350&&mouseX>300&&mouseY>height-50){
    r = 200; g = 200; b = 0;
    
  }
  
  line(width-50,height-50,width-50,0);
  
  ellipse(width-25,50,50,50);

  ellipse(width-25,100,25,25);
  
  ellipse(width-25,150,10,10);
 
  ellipse(width-25,200,75,75);
  

  
  rect(width-50,height-50,50,50);
  
}



void mousePressed(){
  if(mouseX<width&&mouseX>width-50&&mouseY>height-50){
    saveFrame();
  }
  
  if(mouseX>width-50&&mouseY>50-15&&mouseY<50+15){
    penSize = 50;
    
  }
  if(mouseX>width-50&&mouseY<100+15&&mouseY>100-15){
    penSize = 25;
    
  }
  if(mouseX>width-50&&mouseY<150+15&&mouseY>150-15){
    penSize = 10;
    
  }
  if(mouseX>width-50&&mouseY<200+15&&mouseY>200-15){
    penSize = 75;
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you call `stroke()`/`strokeWeight()`, by default, the settings are applied globally. When you selected the thickest stroke, currently, **everything** else in the sketch will have the same stroke weight.

You can however easily reset the stroke properties to defaults (e.g. `stroke(0)`, `strokeWeight(3)`) after drawing the user's line.

Here's a modified version of your code with the above stroke reset applied (and
commenting/organising similar instructions for easier reading):

```java
float r = 0;
float g = 0;
float b = 0;

int penSize = 1;

void setup() {
  size(800, 650);
  background(255);
}

void draw() {
  // draw applying user settings
  stroke(r, g, b);
  strokeWeight(penSize);
  if (mousePressed&&mouseY<height-50&&mouseX<width-50) {
    line(pmouseX, pmouseY, mouseX, mouseY);
  }

  // reset to default stroke
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(1);

  // draw UI - colors
  line(0, height-50, width-50, height-50);
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  rect(0, height-50, 50, 50);
  fill(0, 255, 0);
  rect(50, height-50, 50, 50);
  fill(0, 0, 255);
  rect(100, height-50, 50, 50);
  fill(255);
  rect(150, height-50, 50, 50);
  fill(0);
  rect(200, height-50, 50, 50);
  fill(100, 0, 255);
  rect(250, height-50, 50, 50);
  fill(200, 200, 0);
  rect(300, height-50, 50, 50);
  // draw UI - stroke size
  line(width-50, height-50, width-50, 0);

  ellipse(width-25, 50, 50, 50);

  ellipse(width-25, 100, 25, 25);

  ellipse(width-25, 150, 10, 10);

  ellipse(width-25, 200, 75, 75);
  // save button
  rect(width-50, height-50, 50, 50);
}



void mousePressed() {
  // save screenshot (including UI)
  if (mouseX<width&&mouseX>width-50&&mouseY>height-50) {
    saveFrame();
  }
  // select stroke size
  if (mouseX>width-50&&mouseY>50-15&&mouseY<50+15) {
    penSize = 50;
  }
  if (mouseX>width-50&&mouseY<100+15&&mouseY>100-15) {
    penSize = 25;
  }
  if (mouseX>width-50&&mouseY<150+15&&mouseY>150-15) {
    penSize = 10;
  }
  if (mouseX>width-50&&mouseY<200+15&&mouseY>200-15) {
    penSize = 75;
  }
  // select stroke color
  if (mouseX<50&&mouseY>height-50) {
    r = 255;
    g = 0;
    b = 0;
  }
  if (mouseX<100&&mouseX>50&&mouseY>height-50) {
    r = 0;
    g = 255;
    b = 0;
  }
  if (mouseX<150&&mouseX>100&&mouseY>height-50) {
    r = 0;
    g = 0;
    b = 255;
  }
  if (mouseX<200&&mouseX>150&&mouseY>height-50) {
    r = 255;
    g = 255;
    b = 255;
  }
  if (mouseX<250&&mouseX>200&&mouseY>height-50) {
    r = 0;
    g = 0;
    b = 0;
  }
  if (mouseX<300&&mouseX>250&&mouseY>height-50) {
    r = 100;
    g = 0;
    b = 255;
  }
  if (mouseX<350&&mouseX>300&&mouseY>height-50) {
    r = 200;
    g = 200;
    b = 0;
  }
}
```

FWIW here are a few related answers that might be useful for next steps (e.g. if OOP was taught, etc.):

- you can also isolate drawing styles with [`pushStyle()`/`popStyle()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506670/in-processing-is-there-matrix-stack-for-common-attributes/9513295#9513295)
- if you need to implement layers, you can using [`PGraphics`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55900614/how-can-put-image-back-of-paints-which-i-drew/55902167#55902167)
- if you need to draw shapes (e.g. ellipses, rectangles) and handle selection [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189470/processing-having-object-oriented-programming-issues/34792466#34792466) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67741843/how-to-create-a-new-objectrectangle-everytime-when-the-button-is-clicked/67766664#67766664) answer might help.